# How to use bitwise operator in existing sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sql query. I have column name "ExpenseBucketCoverage" in claim table in which I am storing bitwise operators store multiple values in one column like below

```
MED_COPAY = 1, MED_DED= 10, MED_COINS = 100, RX_COPAY = 1, RX_DED= 10, RX_COINS = 100
```

I want to replace hard coded value like `MED_COPAY`, `MED_COINS`, `MED_DED`, `RX_DED`, `RX_COINS` & `RX_COPAY` in query by using `ExpenseBucketCoverage`  column value. Can some one please tell me how can I do that?

Someone has suggested me below soultion

> retrieve data from  claim and left joining the first matched record in eligibility. And then add custom code to loop through the datarows to split the rows by covered expense bucket, and set the service category code in-memory column based on the ExpenseBucketCoverage value for the claim.

```
SELECT 
e.categoryid,
c.servicetype,
'II' AS RepordType, 
e.TPAId AS TPA_Id,
e.EmployerCode,
e.SubscriberId,
e.MemberID,
c.ServiceFrom,
c.ServiceTo,  
CASE 
    WHEN e.categoryid IN( 'MED_DED', 'RX_DED' ) THEN 
        deductible 
    WHEN e.categoryid IN( 'MED_COINS', 'RX_COINS' ) THEN 
        isnull(coins,0) 
    WHEN e.categoryid IN( 'MED_COPAY', 'RX_COPAY' ) THEN 
        copay 
        ELSE 0
        END AS ClaimAmount,  
'' AS AccountTypeCode, 
'1' ClaimsCrossoverAutoPay, 
e.CategoryId,   
    CASE c.ServiceType 
        WHEN 'H' THEN 
            CASE e.PayeeIndicator 
                WHEN 'N' THEN '0' 
                WHEN 'Y' THEN '1' 
        END 
        WHEN 'P' THEN '0' 
        END AS PayProvider,  
    CASE c.ServiceType 
        WHEN 'H' THEN 
        CASE PayeeIndicator 
            WHEN 'N' THEN '0' 
            WHEN 'Y' THEN '1' 
            END 

        WHEN 'P' THEN '0' 
            END AS ReimbursementMethod,  

    CASE c.ServiceType 
        WHEN 'H' THEN c.Provider 
        WHEN 'P' THEN '' 
        END AS ProviderId,  
'1' EnforceAccountEffectiveDates, 
c.Id, 
c.ClaimNumber + e.CategoryId as 'ExternalClaimNumber', 
c.ProviderName, 
c.CarrierId + ';' + c.SourceClaimNumber AS Notes  
FROM Claim c   
INNER JOIN Eligibility e   ON e.TPAId = c.TPAId AND e.EIN = c.EIN AND  
 c.Processed = 'Y' AND e.FilterType = 'Eligibility'  
 AND c.TPAId='PrimePay'  
 AND (c.ServiceFrom   >= e.BenefitEffectiveDate 
 AND c.ServiceFrom           <=e.BenefitTermDate)   
 AND (  (  c.PayorID = c.PatientSSN
 AND e.SubscriberSSN = c.PatientSSN   
 AND (c.EmployeeFirstName = c.PatientFirstName 
 AND c.EmployeeLastName = c.PatientLastName)  
 AND(e.MemberSSN = '' OR e.MemberSSN = NULL)  
 AND(e.MemberFirstName = '' OR e.MemberFirstName = NULL)
 AND(e.MemberLastName = '' OR e.MemberLastName = NULL))
 OR((c.PayorID !=  c.PatientSSN AND e.MemberSSN = c.PatientSSN 
 AND  e.MemberFirstName = c.PatientFirstName 
 AND e.MemberLastName = c.PatientLastName)  
 OR(c.PayorID != c.PatientSSN AND e.MemberFirstName = c.PatientFirstName 
 AND e.MemberLastName= c.PatientLastName)))
 AND (( c.Servicetype ='P' 
 AND e.CategoryID IN('RX_COINS','RX_COPAY', 'RX_DED' )) 
 OR ( c.Servicetype = 'H' 
 AND e.CategoryID IN( 'MED_COINS','MED_COPAY', 'MED_DED' )))
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output?

Comment: Why are you storing multiple values in one column? Are you aware that this is a violation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form ?

Comment: @MarkBannister thanks for your comment, see this example to choose multiple values into single column. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1218/sql-server-bitwise-operators-store-multiple-values-in-one-column/

Comment: @M005: In the example cited, the author doesn't explain **why** there is a necessity to combine multiple different values into a single field.

Comment: @MarkBannister the reason why I am doing this is because I do not want to add new columns into my existing database, there may be many more fields like this in future, so to avoid adding column every time for specific group may not good idea. but you are right it is violation of normalization rule.